# How to extend string limit, while converting it from MYSQL database to excel in dropdown list using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, phpexcel

I'm trying to get my MySQL data to Excel file as dropdownlist, but I'm having problems with its string limit. The excel file get corrupted if string limit exceed from 255. Here is my code:

```
foreach ($sequence as $sequence_no) {
if ($pattern_record['attribute_' . $sequence_no . '_name'] != "") {
    $cell = $objWorkSheet->getCell($column . $row);
    $cell->setValue($pattern_record['attribute_' . $sequence_no . '_name']);
    if (!empty($pattern_record['attribute_' . $sequence_no . '_variable_value'])) {
        for ($j = 2; $j <= $no_emp; $j++) {
            $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            $excel->getActiveSheet()
                    ->setCellValue($column . "" . $j, "");
            $configs = $pattern_record['attribute_' . $sequence_no . '_variable_value'];
            $objValidation = $excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($column . $j)->getDataValidation();
            $objValidation->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
            $objValidation->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
            $objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
            $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
            $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
            $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
            $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
            $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
            $objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
            $objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
            $objValidation->setFormula1('"' . $configs . '"');
        }
    }

    //check and set datatype in excel
    //General format
    else if (in_array($sequence_no, $datatype_varchar)) {
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column)
                ->getNumberFormat()
                ->setFormatCode(
                        PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT
        );
    } else if (in_array($sequence_no, $datatype_text)) {
        //text format
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column)
                ->getNumberFormat()
                ->setFormatCode(
                        '0'
        );
    } else if (in_array($sequence_no, $datatype_int)) {

        // numerical format
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column)
                ->getNumberFormat()
                ->setFormatCode(
                        '0'
        );
    } else if (in_array($sequence_no, $datatype_date)) {

        // date format
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column)->getNumberFormat()
                ->setFormatCode('yyyy-mm-dd');
    }
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("$column$row:$column$row")->getFont()->setSize(14);
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("$column:$column")->getFont()->setSize(12);

    $excel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension($column)
            ->setAutoSize(true);
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row . ':' . $column . $row)->getFill()
            ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
            ->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE8E5E5');


    $col++;
    $column++;
} }
```

It is downloading properly if data it is in between 255 length but get corrupted if it is exceed. Please suggest something.

Comment: Use this echo clean('a|"bc!@£de^&$f g');

Comment: hi @NimeShPatel i edited my code, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the data directly into the dropdown. Write it to a set of cells, and then set the dropdown to the cellrange. That way, it's not restricted by the MS Excel string limit for a data validation list